# Spring boot and flyway integration - init order

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have an EntityManager (and a DataSource) created by spring boot and i want to add flyway. but EntityManager must be created after flyway and flyway after the DataSource. do i have to create whole EntityManager manually only to add 'depends-on' or is there some simpler way?

Comment: What's a session factory? Why does it need to be created after flyway?

Comment: hibernate's session factory - i updated the question. it has to be created/initialized after flyway because first flyway changes the database and later hibernate validates the schema

Comment: Did you find a solution?... I'm stuck just the same

Comment: yes, but still haven't have time to check Dave Syer solution. `@Configuration
public class DbConfig extends HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration 
{

 @Bean
 public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory(JpaVendorAdapter jpaVendorAdapter, Flyway flyway) {
  return super.entityManagerFactory(jpaVendorAdapter);
 }
}`

Answer (score 1):

Boot doesn't create a Hibernate `SessionFactory` so probably you mean a JPA `EntityManager`. If you create your own `Flyway` it will always be initialized before the Boot autoconfig beans. Is that not what you see? Maybe you need to share a project.

Comment: you're right. i'm talking about EntityManager. but flyway depends on datasource. so what i got is: datasource and entitymanger are created and called @PostConstruct and later flyway is initialized. which is too late

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the details yet. Can you put the code in github? [The sagan project](https://github.com/spring-io/sagan/) uses Flyway, Boot and Hibernate JPA, if that's any help.

Comment: but in this project DataSource is built manually and flyway migration is called explicitly with `configureDataSource`. i don't want to create DataSource manually. i want to use the one created by spring boot

Comment: This [sample](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/tree/master/spring-boot-samples/spring-boot-sample-flyway) has autoconfig for everything and it works (with 1.1.0, but I'm sure something siumilar would have to work for 1.0.x).

Comment: @DaveSyer: Even if this is not my question, I'm stuck just the same. As far as I can tell, the example you suggest works because in 1.1.0 exists a flyway auto-configuration, but that's not the case in 1.0.x. Am I right?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in the usage of `spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=validate` (Hibernate wants to validate the `DataSource` before the migrations are executed, see [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/894)). A simple workaround is to switch to `spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=none`.

Comment: ahem.  that is a "broken" work-around as it doesn't accomplish the goal: validating the current set of JPA/Hibernate mappings against the up-to-date db schema.

Comment: The link above is to an issue that is marked as resolved, so probably the workaround is no longer necessary.

Comment: Marked as closed.  My exp is it's not resolved. Could well be that I'm doing something wrong.  But my config seems rather vanilla.  I've opened a new ticket in GH as you suggested.